# use Excel Objects (Worksheet, Workbooks ...) in Classes/Objects

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

i've got a problem with the import of Excel Worksheets into a summary Workbook.

First i try to import the data as DataTable, using:

```
`Dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            tableName = GetTableNames(Dt);

            com = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuery(tableName[0]), conn);

            com.Fill(DtSet);

            Dt = DtSet.Tables[0];`
```

works fine except the fact, that some of the headline got lost, after copy the data to a new sheet:

```
private static void ImportData(DataTable source, string p)
    {
        int pos = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
        object lastSheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(pos);
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, lastSheet, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        ws.Name = p;
        // column headings
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[1, i + 1] = source.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }

        // rows
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // to do: format datetime values before printing
            for (var j = 0; j < source.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = source.Rows[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Second, i hoped to import fix that by importing it via interop so i implemented this one:

```
        public Excel.Worksheet GetWorksheet(string path)
    {
        Excel.Application vApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook vBook = vApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = vBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        vBook.Close();
        vApp.Quit();
        return ws;
    }
```

seems to work also fine, until i try to copy this sheet to the active Workbook:

```
        private static void ImportData(Excel.Worksheet source, string p)
    {
        int pos = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
        source.Copy(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets[pos]);            
    }
```

this should copy the source to the last position within `Globals.ThisWorkbook`... but all i got is a COMException

Now i run out of ideas how to fix this. 
Hope you can help.

Mirko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the guy posted this here: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902217/why-excel-worksheet-copy-throws-exception-of-a-first-chance-exception-of-type-s)

I need to load the source workbook into the active application instead of starting an own application and get the worksheet from there:

```
            Excel.Application destApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
            Excel.Workbook destWB = destApp.Workbooks[1];
            Excel.Workbook sourceWB = destApp.Workbooks.Open(d.Path);
            int pos = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
            Excel.Worksheet destWS = ((Excel.Worksheet)destWB.Worksheets[pos]);
            Excel.Worksheet sourceWS = ((Excel.Worksheet)sourceWB.Worksheets[1]);
            sourceWS.Name = d.Name;
            sourceWB.Save();
            sourceWS.Copy(destWS);
            sourceWB.Close();
```

Thats all and its pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to use COM objects. Try, OpenXML and ClosedXML to create excel sheets dynamically.

[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/closed-xml-to-read-excel-files-in-asp-net-c-sharp/]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thansk for your comment, the problem is using external libraries or software isn't allowed in my company before an approval. The software needs to be finished within two days, the approval takes to long. :-)

Comment: Yes I can understand. You are using Microsoft.Interop.Excel Right? I too had used it. Our product was hosted in the cloud server purchased by client. We could not convince our client to install Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assembly package in the server. So I used openXML and ClosedXML which is absolutely free. Performance was also great with efficient code.